# How to trigger an action on QR Code scan using ZBAR for Android?

Tags: android, qr-code, zbar

I am using ZBar android library to scan QR Codes. Till now, the codes are scanned and the scan result is shown in textView. I want to trigger action when the code is scanned, like other apps that scan qr codes and trigger the action accordingly. Here is my implementation

```
public class CameraTestActivity extends Activity
{
   private Camera mCamera;
   private CameraPreview mPreview;
   private Handler autoFocusHandler;

   TextView scanText;
   Button scanButton;

   ImageScanner scanner;

   private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
   private boolean previewing = true;

   static {
       System.loadLibrary("iconv");
   } 

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        /* Instance bar code scanner */

        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        scanText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanText);

        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                if (barcodeScanned) {
                    barcodeScanned = false;
                    scanText.setText("Scanning...");
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    previewing = true;
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
                  }
               }
            });
    }

     public void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         releaseCamera();
     }

     /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
     public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
       }
        return c;
     }

    private void releaseCamera() {
         if (mCamera != null) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (previewing)
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
            }
    };

    PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

            Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
            barcode.setData(data);

            int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

            if (result != 0) {
                previewing = false;
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();

                SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();

                for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                    scanText.setText("barcode result " + sym.getData());
                    barcodeScanned = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
              autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
         }
      };
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried the Handler class which consist on callback function ?

Comment: No. Can you give any example? I am using this library for first time,

Comment: Try this library. [link](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) It also has fragment support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i had used zbar and used this code to trigger an alert dialog on a successful scan:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            // Handle successful scan
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            //contents has your scanned string
            //you can trigger your action here


        } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```